# Fill out google form using an api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a private google form I need to fill out every day, so I would like to write a script to authenticate me using my google credentials, and then fill out some of the form programatically, is there an API for that? What is a recommended approach for this, without having edit access to the form?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

Comment: Ok so that is the one. I thought it was for creating forms only

Comment: The Forms Service from Google Apps Script requires edit access to the form in order to be able to create a response programatically.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is super-late, but I just found your question via google since I had the same thought. The answer is query parameters. [According to this article about using merge tags in Mailchimp to auto-populate google forms](https://trevorfox.com/2015/06/dynamically-pre-fill-google-forms-with-mailchimp-merge-tags/), if you pass query parameters after the form URL in the format `form.url?key=value`, e.g.`https://docs.google.com/forms/path/to/stub?<entry.###########>=<url-encoded prefill value>`. After generating the form, inspect the field you want to prefill. Its `name` attribute will be in the format `<entry.###########>`, where `.###########>` is some long number. Fill in `<url-encoded prefill value>` with whatever you want to go into that form, as long as it is properly URL-encoded. Hope that helps anyone else with the same question as us.